# How to batch requests with react realy?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, react-relay

Currently I'm fetching data like this:

```
const SomeComponent = ({variable}) => {
 const data = useLazyLoadQuery(
   NewsfeedQuery,
   {variable},
 );

 //...
}
```

This works fine, but calling this component with 10 different variables, will result in 10 separate requests.

Is it possible to batch this 10 queries together into a single request?

Comment: See https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/multiple-queries-in-a-single-graphql-request